# CSS: limit element to 1 line

Tags: css

I want to limit a element to display only 1 line of text, with the remainder hidden (overflow:hidden), without setting a specific height. Is this possible with just CSS?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It is possible:

```
element (white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll;)
```

Text parsed as HTML or XML is tokenized, which means all runs of whitespace are collapsed to a single space character.  This means you will have a single line of text unless you specify something in addition to the overflow declaration that could cause your text to wrap.

EDIT: I failed to include the necessary write-space: nowrap property, otherwise the default is that a container will scroll vertically opposed to horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for adding all the additional info.

Comment: i know this is old but this top answer fails if the text I want to display has line breaks. It would display the second line content with nowrap. I want to limit to displaying only the first line and preserving the line breaks. And none of the other answers seem to address this issue.

Answer (score 51):

use display block so it won't go beyond your parent element.

```
p#foo{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 36):

```
p#foo {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking to disable text wrapping, use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 1):

The new line height unit `height: 1lh;` may be helpful

1lh is 1 line, 2lh is 2 lines, etc

Line height varies according to font size

Browser support is picking up: https://caniuse.com/?search=lh%20unit

Here's a demo:

```css
.lh1 {
  height: 1lh;
}

.lh2 {
  height: 2lh;
}

.small {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.large {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small lh1">
  1 line small font 00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
</div>

<div class="large lh1">
  1 line large font 00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                    00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
</div>

<div class="small lh2">
  2 lines small font 00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
</div>

<div class="large lh2">
  2 lines large font 00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
                     00000 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you want to display elements to the left of truncated text, `white-space: nowrap;` does not help. Then this might be useful:

```
.truncated {
  max-height: 1.33em; /* Or whatever line height works for you */
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```