# How to limit a table cell to one line of text using CSS?

Tags: css, html-table, overflow

I have a table of users where each row contains their names, e-mail address, and such. For some users this row is one text line high, for some others two, etc. But I would like that each row of the table be one text line high, truncating the rest.

I saw these two questions:

- [A column of a table needs to stay in one line (HTML/CSS/Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779779/a-column-of-a-table-needs-to-stay-in-one-line-html-css-javascript)
- [CSS: limit element to 1 line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318108/css-limit-element-to-1-line)

In fact my question is exactly similar to the first one, but since the link is dead I can't study it. Both answers say to use `white-space: nowrap`. However this doesn't work, maybe I'm missing something.

Since I can't show you the code, I reproduced the problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
}
</style>

<div style="width:500px">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum here... blablablablablablablablablabla</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum here... blablablablablablablablablabla</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum here... blablablablablablablablablabla</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum here... blablablablablablablablablabla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Without `white-space` the table is 500px wide, and the text takes more than one line.

But `white-space: nowrap` makes the browser simply ignore the `width` directive and increase the width of the table until all data fits in one line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not in this example, but on my real website yes. Anyway I don't think not having a doctype is related to this problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

overflow will only work if it knows where to start considering it overflown. You need to set the width and height attribute of the `<td>`

**TAKE 2**

Try adding `table-layout: fixed; width:500px;` to the table's style.

**UPDATE 3**

confirmed this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/e3Eqn/

Comment: I had already tried it before asking the question and it doesn't work either. I edited the question to add it

Comment: @Tomaka17, I edited my answer to include additional instructions.

Comment: Is there any way to just say "the overflow is what the element size would be if this element wasn't in it"?

Comment: In addition, adding `text-overflow:ellipsis` would help users distinguish between the cells displaying the whole data from those who need more space & has truncated values.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link. Was all i needed!

Answer (score 64):

Add the following code to your stylesheet:

```
table { 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
table{
     width: 500px; table-layout:fixed;
}
```

You need to add the table width to ensure that the next property will fit the elements to the specified size. The table-layout property here forces the browser to use a fixed layout within the 500 pixels it's given.

Answer (score 3):

```html
  <table border="1" style="width:200px">
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td nowrap="nowrap">
    
  Single line cell just do it</td>
   <td>
 
  multiple lines here just do it</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Simple And Useful.
use above code for

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1" style="width:200px">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">Single line cell just do it</td>
    <td>multiple lines here just do it</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```