# HTML/CSS - how can I make my table columns never go wider what i speficy as width

Tags: html, css

I have  `<td width="25%">` but if it gets populated with something thats largers than 25% it gets bigger. how can I stop it from getting bigger than 25% with css or html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the css `table-layout:fixed` on the table

Found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

Comment: +1, way easier (more concise, and more elegant) than my own proposed solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max-width: 25%;` to prevent the maximum width from being exceeded; having said that this is a css solution, rather than an html-attribute, so you'd have to use:

```
<td style="max-width: 25%;">...</td>
```

Or, better yet, specify in the stylesheet:

```
td {
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

As @Asherer correctly notes (in the comments) this won't necessarily work in all browsers. To enforce the `max-width` it might be worth wrapping the contents of the `td` in a `div` (or, if they're in-line elements, a `span`) and applying the `max-width` to *that* element.

For example:

```
<td>
    <div>
        Cell contents
    </div>
</td>

td {
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}

td div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* or 'auto', or 'scroll' */
}
```

This can get a bit messy over time, and I'm not usually a fan of adding unnecessary mark-up, but in this case it *does* aid the cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the max-width style attribute, and set it to 25%.

```
td{
   max-width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this SO thread. It might be useful [How to limit a table cell to one line of text using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379220/how-to-limit-a-table-cell-to-one-line-of-text-using-css)

Here's some CSS that may help you:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table{
    table-layout:fixed; 
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to test it at the moment but I believe `overflow:hidden` on `td` doesn't work in IE. Worth a try.

Comment: Just tested this site (where I got the CSS sample from) http://jsfiddle.net/e3Eqn/ in IE 9 and it seems to work fine.