# Limit cell width with CSS and hide overflow - IE anomaly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I am having problems with a table.

It's made of 3 cells each row, each cell has a max width and the text that doesn't fit in the cells has to be discarded.

I already looked this:

[How to limit a table cell to one line of text using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379220/how-to-limit-a-table-cell-to-one-line-of-text-using-css)

And I made the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3Eqn/222/

The problem is that I don't understand why Firefox, Chrome, Safari are ok with it and Internet Explorer displays a crazy formatting and does not consider the `overflow:hidden`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem again. However there is a easier workaround than to plunge in various techniques instead.

Use this format

```
<td>
<div>
Your longlonglongcontent
</div>
</td>
```

Then use this as CSS

```
td div { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

This will work in ff, opera and IE7

See your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Eqn/238/) with this hack

Comment: I entered your code in the fiddle, but the problem remains in IE 7:  http://jsfiddle.net/e3Eqn/240/